# Can I install Visual Studio Code in Docker for security?

Tags: software-installation, security, snap, visual-studio-code, flatpak

Would installing Visual Studio Code in a Docker container offer better isolation than a snap or Flatpack?

Comment: Why you need isolation, please describe your usage scenario? If you don't trust Microsoft, use `vscodium` instead of `vscode`. `docker` is not made for this.

Comment: I don't know if it's really a matter of trust, but if people choose Linux mainly because they don't trust Windows 10' creators (NO privacy, etc.) then why should I give them this gateway through this app? Can you prove otherwise?

Comment: I tried to install it via snap but I have this message. Something stinks here.

"This revision of snap "codium" was published using classic confinement
       and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security
       sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at
       risk.
"

Answer (score 2):

#### Code_OSS AppImage

Unlike other applications, AppImages do not need to be installed before they can be used, however they need to be marked as executable before they can be run. This is a Linux security feature.

**Visual Studio Code OSS Edition:**

Download the [Code_OSS AppImage](https://appimage.github.io/Code_OSS/) and make it executable using your file manager or by entering the following commands in a terminal:

```
chmod +x ./*.AppImage
```

Then double-click the AppImage in the file manager to open it.

**Sandboxing Code_OSS:**

If you want to restrict what Code_OSS can do on your system, you can run the AppImage in a sandbox like Firejail. This is entirely optional and currently needs to be configured by the user.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) has already [stated](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2125187) that docker isn't made for this. If you're concerned about running Visual Studio Code in a *sandbox*, snaps and AppImages would be a better option.

But if you're still interested in running Visual Studio Code inside a Docker container, you can follow below steps:

#### Preparing the docker container

Create a new Dockerfile inside an empty folder, for example, "myimage" and add

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y gpg sudo
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
RUN apt update
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y code
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y libx11-xcb1
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y libxtst6
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y libasound2
CMD /usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --unity-launch
```

Build the container:

```
sudo docker build -t myimage .
```

#### Running Visual Studio Code:

Run the container using:

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=host -e DISPLAY=:0  myimage
```

If you get

```
(code:1): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Run

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

Retry running the container.

#### Creating Desktop Entry a.k.a. shortcut

Since docker needs `sudo` privileges to run, you can use [`pkexec`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkexec) inside the desktop entry. To create a shortcut, run

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/vscode-docker.desktop
```

and add these contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=VSCode Docker
Icon=code
Exec=bash -c 'pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /usr/bin/docker run --rm -t --net=host -e DISPLAY=:0 myimage'
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

**Note:** Since the desktop entry uses `pkexec`, docker needs to be run non-interactively , i.e., without `i` option.

Comment: But why not the docker? I mean, what's worse than a snap/flatpack because I don't understand ?