# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: xorg, gui, docker

I followed the answer given to [Run simple X11 app in docker container on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249043/) precisely without any luck. I got the following error messages:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with 64-bit and GNOME version is 3.36.3.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know which application you're trying to run and how you installed docker but I [posted an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257701/816190) to a similar question. Does that help?

Comment: [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy), thank you for your response. I am not quite understand your answer. I am trying to follow [Håkon Hægland](https://askubuntu.com/users/156688/h%c3%a5kon-h%c3%a6gland) suggestion to run a simple X11 application in docker container on Ubuntu 20.04. I am asking help for error that comes up with that solution. Thanks,

Comment: I have same issue, and the problem is ARM processor I use